# Get the rugs out there

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I cannot understand the meaning of "get the rugs out there" in this sentence.

> Hopefully, we should get the rugs out there. That would be awesome for me,
>   so, between all six of you guys, you better catch something.

Context: we are on a yacht and the speaker is the yacht chef talking to the guests on the boat. Basically, he is suggesting that they could go out and catch fish that he then can cook for dinner.

Comment: It's not an established idiom, so my guess is it's just a literal usage. Where "there" refers to some place where they'll moor up the boat to have lunch on dry land, and he's talking about putting down ***picnic*** blankets / rugs / tablecloths on the sand / grass. Have you read any further? Is that in fact what happens later?

Comment: To clarify, were you personally on this boat? Or is this from a book, film or tv? The context looks very odd.  Why would a chef be asking the *guests* to start fishing? Is it possible that you misheard? Its not a standard idiom.

Comment: Hi James! No, it is an episode from a reality show called Below Deck.

Comment: We have no hope of penetrating the meaning of “rugs” intended here unless you can give us more context. (A clip? A transcript?)

Comment: Yes, the episode is here https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5bym53 (from 19'15'')

Comment: to get something out somewhere means just that. You need to get the glasses out there. To put them out so people can use them. Get the rugs out there means to put the rugs on the deck so people can use them.

Answer (score -1):

it may have a figuratively and metaphorically meaning:
rug = *BrE* a large piece of material that you can wrap around yourself, especially when you are travelling (according to Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English)

Comment: I'm not sure that fits the exact expression, which is "*hopefully* we can get the rugs *out there*"

Comment: rug is the same in AmE and I have no idea of any idiom like that.

Comment: There is no way this answer fits. They are using American English in this show and a “rug” as a blanket to keep warm, doesn’t fit the sentence. It’s a yacht on the Caribbean too.